# Gimp export batch with edit

Tags: gimp, gimpfu

I want to export a deck of cards. I want to programmatically update the `Value` text field [A,1,2,3....]. Is there a plugin that can do this? Or will I have to explore Gimp scripting? Any guidance would be appreciated.

I'm new to gimp so go easy on me.

Also I've noticed this conversation is related. [How to replace text in Gimp image programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69199531/how-to-replace-text-in-gimp-image-programatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With existing scripts, what I would do is create a group with each of the values as layers (or subgroups), and then use [`ofn-export-layer-combinations`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/) to make each layer/subgroup visible in turn and export the resulting image. So, starting with this:

[image]

You get this:

[image]

To produce multiple decks, you can also have another group with all your backgrounds, and the script will iterate both groups.